# golang : how to convert type interface {} to array

Tags: json, go, redis

I have a JSON array with objects in Redis that I want to loop through it, but when I fetch the data, the type is interface{}, so I cannot range over type interface{}

```golang
array := redis.Do(ctx, "JSON.GET", "key")

arrayResult, e := array.Result()

if e != nil {
    log.Printf("could not get json with command  %s", e)
}

for _, i := range arrayResult {
    fmt.Printf(i)
}
```

Comment: When I try to unmarshal the method result, it say 'Cannot use 'arrayResult' (type interface{}) as the type []byte'

Comment: what is happening in `redis.Do(ctx, "JSON.GET", "key")`, what is the return type of `Do` method?

Comment: the return type of `redis.Do(ctx, "JSON.GET", "key")` is `*redis.Cmd` and the return type of `array.Result()` is `interface{}`

Comment: In go interface{} is an empty interface i.e. an object of any type. You will need to cast it into the proper type to be able to do anything. You may be able to check for the underlying type using `fmt.Printf("%T\n", arrayResult)`

Comment: I am using redis.NewClient

Comment: Which redis package are you using?

Comment: Although I still don't know what package you're using (`redis.NewClient` not actually a package name I think), I'm guessing it might be `github.com/gomodule/redigo`, and if so, I recommend you use something like [this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#String), of course, in your case you should replace with strings maybe.

Comment: I beleive it return JSON, so try to marshall it into a struct which can be a list

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665057/marshal-interface-into-json

Your question would be easier to answer if you gave some sample data of your interface looks like as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you  guys, I found a solution. so at first I needed to convert the arrayResult to byte. Then I unmarshal it into a strcut, so now I am able to range over it.

```
array := redis.Do(ctx, "JSON.GET", "key")
arrayResult, e := array.Result()
if e != nil {
   log.Printf("could not get json with command  %s", e)
}

byteKey := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v", arrayResult.(interface{})))
RedisResult := struct{}
errUnmarshalRedisResult := json.Unmarshal(byteKey, &RedisResult)
if errUnmarshalRedisResult != nil {
       log.Printf("cannot Unmarshal msg %s", errUnmarshalRedisResult)
}

for _, i := range RedisResult {
   fmt.Printf(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do

```
for _, i := range arrayResult.([]byte) {
// do work here
}
```